# How to create or edit tunnel Wireguard on Windows Standard User

Tags: vpn, wireguard

Please help me how the Standard User can create a tunnel or editing a tunnel Wireguard on Windows 10.

pict Wireguard as Admin user
[image]

pict Wireguard as Standard user
[image]

Comment: Odd, my regular user can add/edit/remove tunnels - perhaps you installed it wrong